# Can a Zigbee device receive an OTA update through a different manufacturers hub?

Tags: zigbee

One of the supposed advantages of Zigbee application profiles such as Home Automation is that devices from different manufacturers can work together, so in theory you can use one generic hub (e.g. SmartThings) instead of several proprietry ones.

But what happens when a device wants to check for updated firmware over the internet?
Does Zigbee or the  application profile have some kind of standard for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ZigBee standard defines the protocol for the OTA transfer, and also the format of the OTA files. So long as manufacturers implement the standard, then it is possible to use any hub to load new firmware into any device.

You can find these definitions in the ZigBee Cluster Library documentation.